# PHP/Mysql gallery code change removed images, how to fix it?

Tags: php, mysql

I've problem with my gallery. My url was with numeric I needed to change to mixed with numeric and words. And I changed `$fid = $_GET['name'];` before was `$_GET['id']` and now images aren't showing. What to do?

Mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gallery` (
`id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `des` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fid` int(12) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $fid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["name"]);
    $book= mysql_query("SELECT * from books WHERE id='$fid'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($books) != 0) { 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($books); 
?>

<?php 
$fid = $_GET['name'];
$gallery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id='$fid'") or die (mysql_error());
    while($gal = mysql_fetch_array($gallery)){
    $linkgal = $gal['link'];
    $title = $gal['title'];
    $id = $gal['id'];
    $fid = $gal['fid'];

    echo "'<img src='/uploads/gallery/$linkgal' title='$title' alt='$title' style='height:180px; margin-left:23px;cursor: pointer;'";

    echo 'onclick="PopupCenter';
    echo "('/photos.php?fid=$fid&id=$id', 'xtf', '990', '670')";
    echo '"/>';
    }   
    ?>
```

Comment: your id is an integer so only numbers will ever be valid

Comment: After changing it to $_GET['name'] are you calling it as ?name=thisname?

Comment: Unidentified index shows me.
@user2182349 how to call ?

Comment: so now you add an actual error -we can't guess what is going on, you need to provide details

Comment: I've added in question you can look now.

Comment: If you changed from `id` to `name` then you need to change the sql's where clause to match, `WHERE id=` would no longer be correct. It's also unclear what the second block of PHP code is. This conditional is never closed `if(mysql_num_rows($books) != 0) { `..

Comment: you call it `name` but your still only searching `id`, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've done.I've added array and $_GET.Now it's work.
Actually it's open another window and images are there.How to make to work with jquery like this for example: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/jquery-gallery-solutions/galleria-jquery-image-slideshow-tools-free.jpg

```
  <?php 

    >       $id = $_GET['name'];
    >       $book = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `name`='$id'") or die (mysql_error());
    >       $books = mysql_fetch_array($book);
    >       $id = $book['id'];
    >       $name = $book['name'];




        $gallery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `fid`='$id' ORDER BY `id`") or die (mysql_error());
            while($gal = mysql_fetch_array($gallery)){
            $linkgal = $gallink'];
            $title = $gal['title'];
            $id = $gal['id'];
            $fid = $gal['fid'];

            echo "'<img src='/uploads/gallery/$linkgal' title='$title' alt='$title' style='height:180px; margin-left:23px;cursor: pointer;'";

            echo 'onclick="PopupCenter';
            echo "('/photos.php?fid=$fid&id=$id', 'xtf', '990', '670')";
            echo '"/>';
            }   
            echo '</div>';
            ?>
```